# copy from tmux to any editor not working

Tags: tmux, vi

**I am trying to copy from `tmux` to my browser.** I followed the post

[Copying between tmux buffers and the system clipboard](http://joncairns.com/2013/06/copying-between-tmux-buffers-and-the-system-clipboard/) which tells me to add

```
setw -g mode-keys vi
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
bind y run-shell "tmux show-buffer | xclip -sel clip -i" \; display-message "Copied tmux buffer to system clipboard"
```

. My new `~/.tmux.conf` looks like the below one :

```
setw -g mode-keys vi
set -g mode-mouse on
set-option -g status on
set-option -g status-interval 2
set-option -g status-utf8 on
set-option -g status-justify "centre"
set-option -g status-left-length 60
set-option -g status-right-length 90
set-option -g status-left "#(~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh left)"
set-option -g status-right "#(~/tmux-powerline/powerline.sh right)"

set-window-option -g window-status-current-format "#[fg=colour235, bg=colour27]?#[fg=colour255, bg=colour27] #I ? #W #[fg=colour27, bg=colour235]?"
bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
bind y run-shell "tmux show-buffer | xclip -sel clip -i" \; display-message "Copied tmux buffer to system clipboard"
```

**After setup,** 
I tried

1. `Ctrl-b` [ (before copy mode)
2. `v` (copy mode)
3. `y` (yank)
4. `Ctrl-b y` (to move to system buffer)
5. Goto browser and paste with `Ctrl-v`

Seems working upto **SETP 4** as I see the message

> Copied tmux buffer to system clipboard

But pasting somewhere (**STEP 5**) else is not working.

I am using ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Does Shift+Insert to paste work?

Comment: @jasonwryan no `Shift+Insert` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same `conf` (https://github.com/iPrayag/dotfiles/blob/master/.tmux.conf) in June 2014 is working. `\,,/` Could be mismatch in configuration before.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same configuration as you and it is working.

```
# Use vim keybindings in copy mode
setw -g mode-keys vi
bind [ copy-mode
unbind ]
bind ] paste-buffer

bind-key -t vi-copy 'v' begin-selection
bind-key -t vi-copy 'y' copy-selection
bind y run-shell "tmux show-buffer | xclip -sel clip -i" \; display-message "Copied tmux buffer to system clipboard"
```

Make sure to reload your tmux configuration file with the command:

```
:source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

Or from the shell

```
tmux source-file ~/.tmux.conf
```

You can also make a shortcut for that :

```
# reload .tmux.conf 
bind-key r source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "Configuration reloaded"
```

Comment: It's seems working upto **Step 4**, but `Ctrl-v` in other editors or browsers is not working.